# C++ find in vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator, find

I am trying to do function that would return postition where occurrence was found in vector. But my return value is always 0 and I'm sure that there is a match.

Here is the code:

```
int findInItemvector(vector<Item> vec, string name)
{
    for(vector<Item>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->getName() == name)
        {
            return it - vec.begin(); 
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::find_if` with a custom predicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your first element does not match, the else branch executes `return`, which leaves the function and rest of your loop is not executed. You want something like:

```
int findInItemvector(vector<Item> vec, string name)
{
    for(vector<Item>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->getName() == name)
        {
            return it - vec.begin(); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, since first item can also be match (in which case `it - vec.begin() == 0`), I suggest you to use other guard value, such as -1 (which can never be valid vector index).

Comment: The real solution to the "not found" problem is to use iterators and return the end iterator. This is, of course, just `std::find`.

Answer (score 5):

Your 'else' clause is the problem: if the first item isn't a match, the 'else' kicks in, and your 'return 0' statement breaks you out of the 'for' loop without trying any of the other elements in the vector.

Try getting rid of the 'else', and moving the 'return 0' to *after* the end of the 'for' loop.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed it. Stupid mistake.

Comment: Also the **break** after the **return** will never be called.

Comment: Also, Vitus has very a good point about returning -1 instead of 0 if there's no match.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will always return 0 because of the way it's currently written. If a match is found in the first item of the vector the result of the subtraction is, of course, zero. If it doesn't match the else part executes and returns 0, and the function exits.

The function should probably look like this

```
int findInItemvector(const vector<Item>& vec, string name)
{
    for(vector<Item>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->getName() == name)
        {
            return it - vec.begin(); 
        }
    }
  return -1;
}
```

Notice that I'm passing the vector by constant reference instead of by value, this will prevent an unnecessary copy of the vector from being made when this function is called.
Also, you should indicate failure using -1, not 0, since the latter is a legitimate result if the string you're looking for is in the first element of the vector.